# ¿Alguien sabe por qué mi programa no calcula el promedio de los 25 números?

Tags: c

El problema de este programa es que a la salida solo dice que el promedio de los valores introducidos es 0, y ya traté de usar cualquier tipo de variable, int, float o double y todas entregan un 0 en la cuenta, espero puedan ayudarme y ajunto el código.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
                            


int main()
{
    // TODO: Declaración de las variables: 
    double VOT, a= 0;
    double N;
    double b;

    
    printf("\nEjemplo 9\n");
    printf("\nA continuación, ingrese la edad de 25 personas\n");
    
    while (a<25){
 
    scanf("%d", &N);
    if (N>=18)
    
        VOT+=N;
        a++;
    }
    
    
    b= VOT/a;                   
    
    
    printf("\nEl promedio de edad de las personas que pueden votar es %f años.\n"), b;
    printf("\nFIN\n");
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

22/10: Luego de corregirlo, el programa no admite ninguna entrada de números. Al instante de ejecutarlo, inmediatamente me devuelve un resultado que es 734 años.

El código ahora:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
                            


int main()
{
    // TODO: Declaración de las variables: 
    double VOT, a= 0;
    double N;
    double b;

    
    printf("\nEjemplo 9\n");
    printf("\nA continuación, ingrese la edad de 25 personas\n");
    
    while (a < 25){
 
    scanf("%lf", &N);
    if (N>=18)
    
        VOT += N;
        a++;
    }
    
    
    b= VOT / a;                   
    
    
    printf("\nEl promedio de edad de las personas que pueden votar es %lf años.\n", b);
    printf("\nFIN\n");
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y no será porque tienes la `b` fuera del `printf`, fuera del paréntesis, cuando vas a imprimir el promedio? Eso así no puede ni compilar, así que dudo mucho que te de ese resultado que dices, puesto que el código no compila y por tanto no se puede ejecutar. Un consejo, si vas a contar cosas usa números enteros. No tiene ningún sentido que el número de personas sea un double, porque con las cosas indivisibles no hay decimales.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar no siempre se dividirá entre 25, puesto que hay una condicional, luego de eso, algunas cosas que veo:

- si tienes todos tus valores como double, debes leerlos como tal, aqui no lo haces

  scanf("%d", &N);
- a la hora que muestras tienes el valor por fuera, aqui

  printf("\nEl promedio de edad de las personas que pueden votar es %f años.\n"), b;

Despues de esto, deberia funcionarte de la siguiente manera:

```
// TODO: DeclaraciC3n de las variables: 
double VOT=0, a = 0;
double N;
double b;

printf ("\nEjemplo 9\n");
printf ("\nA continuaciC3n, ingrese la edad de 25 personas\n");
while (a < 25)
{
    scanf ("%lf", &N);
    if (N >= 18)
VOT += N;
    a++;
}

b = VOT / a;

printf
("\nEl promedio de edad de las personas que pueden votar es %lf aC1os.\n",b);
printf ("\nFIN\n");
system ("PAUSE");

return 0;
```

Comment: Sigue dando como resultado "0.000000 años", aunque cambie todo lo que me has marcado, no sé a qué se pueda deber.

Comment: yo lo acabo de correr y si me da el resultado. Puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el codigo tal y como lo tienes ahora?

Comment: Ya lo edité y muestro el código entero, solo que ahora no me permite ingresar los números, ¿puede ser un error del compilador por ser viejo?

Comment: trata poniendo `VOT=0`, como lo hice a ver.

Comment: Sigue haciendo lo mismo, no me permite ingresar los valores y dice que el promedio es  734 años.